# Making a List Item read-only

Tags: list, list-item, item

I'm a newbie so please be gentle. I have created a List from which I can add Items linked to documents in my Library. So far so good. I am the only person that can upload to new docs to the Library and therefore the only person that can update the List - I am the only one with Edit perms.

When a user (who should only have read access) clicks on an item in the List they get a check-out doc option. How do I get the List to work so that when a user clicks on an item it opens the document (they are all in PDF form) straightaway in another tab without the checkout/checkin functions?

Hope all of this makes sense. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Document Library settings, you can go to Versioning and disable the Check In/Out setting. This is typically used when one needs to place an exclusive lock for editing purposes, but as these are PDFs, editing is unlikely.

Comment: The 'Require Check-Out' setting is already set to No. A User would be able to open the PDF if they accessed via the Document Library directly but they aren't, they're accessing via the List. Versioning for the List has nothing for enabling/disabling Check-Out.  What I want is for a User to be able to click on the Item within the List and open the document directly; at present they get a window with loads of options/icons and a link to the doc which they can then click on (again). I want the doc to open immediately if possible. Cheers